# Visual Studio 2015 hangs when building Droid project of Xamarin.Forms solution

Tags: xamarin, build, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am a newbie in Android. I started to learn Xamarin Forms few days ago. I created a new Project under Cross Platform -> Blank App(Xamarin Forms Portable). Still I have not written any code by my self, but every time when I build the Droid Project, it hangs the Visual Studio (Please see the picture below). Please advise me.

[image]

Comment: I've found sometimes the first run of a new project can take some time due to downloading all of the packages required. You can try looking at your resource monitor to see if it's actually downloading anything.
I'd also consider ensuring your workspace is short and contains no spaces - this can cause some issues. Mine personally is C:\WorkspaceXamarin\

Comment: Xamarin can download several gigs during the first build.  It really should tell you it's doing this, but it doesn't.  Check to see if there are any files being downloaded to `C:\Users\YOU\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips`

Comment: Did you found a solution ? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I want to share my experience,

I have a Xamarin Forms project on Visual Studio 2017 Professional edition.
After a few days, I have installed an update of Visual Studio and building the project became impossible.

At the end of a long search, I realised that it was trying to download a nuget package. And maybe due to a temporary problem, downloading the package was too slow (Tried to download the package from nugets.org directly). And as there is no explication, I had the impression that Visual Studio was hanging during the build.

I searched the package and installed on all projects in my solution, it took 45 minuts but at the end everything was ok.